# Point to new user drive - Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, clone, user

Google isn't being friendly today.  Simply put, I'm trying to clone my user drive (separate from my system drive) to a larger one and just point to the new drive for windows to use and access.  Unfortunately, all I can find is tutorials on how to move individual user folders to a new drive, which I already did with the current one, and that just seems a tad too superfluous.  Does anyone know how to simply just clone the old drive over to the new one and use that from now on, without having to manually repoint all my folders individually?

Thanks a bunch!

Josh

EDIT:  I already have ways to clone the drive.  I just need to get windows to use the new drive and not the old one.

Comment: Have you just tried to clone it and reassign the drive letters once it's been cloned?

Comment: Why can’t you move the user profile, then manually transfer the files from the old drive, to the current drive.  You can also clone the partition with the user profile to the new drive, and afterwords, change the location of the user profile to that new location.  This will skip the manual transfer of the user profile files. You can also change the drive letter...

Comment: If it's that simple, then cheers to me over thinking the problem.  I thought about trying that, but can I do that while the OS is running without any problems?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "user drive". If you're talking about redirecting the Documents, Desktop, and other user folders, simply right-click on these entries in the This PC portion of your File Explorer and tell them where the new files are. It'll ask about moving the files, and you can tell it no. But, there's no such thing in Windows as a "User Drive" so you'll need to be more precise and clear in the words you use in order for us to clearly and correctly understand what you are asking.